# Removing Duplicate Rows From Advantage Database Server 10.1 Table

Tags: sql, dbf, advantage-database-server

I have a large DBF table in ADS that may contain duplicate records.  A duplicate record is identified by any record where field2, field3, field5, field4, field8 and field7 match another record.  I need to identify duplicate records and delete them.  To accomplish this I'm trying to write a set of records to a second table.  Even though a duplicate record is identified by six fields, I need to write the entire record, 30 fields, to the second table.  I have tried the following code:

```
insert into table2 select * from table1 where (
  field2, field3, field5, field4, field8, field7
) in (
  select field2, field3, field5, field4, field8, field7
  from table1 where field3 not like '%FOO%' and field3 not like '%BOO%'
  group by field2, field3, field5, field4, field8, field7 having count(*) > 1
)
```

ADS error message: ERROR IN SCRIPT: poQuery: Error 7200: AQE Error: State = 42000; NativeError = 2115; [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical element not found:) There was a problem parsing the WHERE clause in your SELECT statement.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow. That's not even close to correct SQL syntax in any dialect. :-) Can you post some sample data (based on the columns you need to actually match)? Also, before trying to INSERT, work on just being able to SELECT the rows. When you get that working, *then* figure out how to insert them into another table.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you already have the alternate table available with those columns, you should be good with...

```
insert into table2 
  ( field2, field3, field5, field4, field8, field7 ) 
select 
      field2, field3, field5, field4, field8, field7
   from 
      table1 
   where 
          field3 not like '%FOO%' 
      and field3 not like '%BOO%'
   group by 
      field2, 
      field3, 
      field5, 
      field4, 
      field8, 
      field7 
   having 
      count(*) > 1  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer would be to just delete all duplicate records while keeping just the first one.  Here is what I mean:

```
DECLARE tbl CURSOR;

//1st find duplicate records
OPEN tbl AS SELECT DISTINCT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3...
              FROM (SELECT d1.field1, d1.field2, d1.field3... 
                      FROM table1 d1 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) a ;

//now traverse cursor containing duplicate records
//deleting all duplicates from original table except 
//1st one

WHILE FETCH tbl DO 

    DELETE FROM table1 
     WHERE RowId > ( 
           SELECT MIN( d3.RowId )
             FROM table1 d3
            WHERE d3.field1 = tbl.field1
              AND d3.field2 = tbl.field2
              AND d3.field3 = tbl.field3 ... ) 
       AND table1.field1 = tbl.field1 
       AND table1.field2 = tbl.field2
       AND table1.field3 = tbl.field3 ;

END WHILE ;
CLOSE tbl ;
```

If table1 is indexed on some of these fields (field1, field2, field3...) and there aren't complicated "On Delete" triggers declared on table1 then the operation should perform pretty fast.